# Gross pay program using arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Good morning everybody. I'm a beginner, so bear with me.

For my class, we have to create a C# program that reads a text file, containing the following information: employee ID, department number, hourly salary, and hours worked. The goal is for it to display a list of each department (7 total), with the total gross pay of every employee combined for that department. Hourly salary must be at least 10.00, and hours worked must be greater than 0.

I've got the program to accurately count the number of employees in each department; not required, but helpful for me. When I try to use similar logic to calculate the total hours worked and total hourly pay for each department, I run into trouble.

Here's my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Project3
{
    class Program
    {
        const int DEPARTMENT = 7;
        const int SIZE = 4;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader infile = new StreamReader(fstream);
        string inputRecord = "";
        string[] employee = new string[SIZE];
        int department = 0;
        int[] departmentCount = new int[DEPARTMENT];
        double hourlySalary = 0.0;
        double hoursWorked = 0.0;
        double grossPay = hourlySalary * hoursWorked;
        inputRecord = infile.ReadLine();
        while (inputRecord != null)
        {
            employee = inputRecord.Split(',');
            if (int.TryParse(employee[1], out department) && department > 0 && department <= DEPARTMENT)
                departmentCount[department - 1] = departmentCount[department - 1] + 1;
            else
                Console.WriteLine(inputRecord);
            if (double.TryParse(employee[2], out hourlySalary) && hourlySalary >= 10.0)
                hourlySalary = hourlySalary + hourlySalary;
            else
                Console.WriteLine(inputRecord);
            if (double.TryParse(employee[3], out hoursWorked) && hoursWorked > 0)
                hoursWorked = hoursWorked + hoursWorked;
            else
                Console.WriteLine(inputRecord);
            grossPay = hourlySalary * hoursWorked;
            inputRecord = infile.ReadLine();
        }//end while
        showOutput(departmentCount, hourlySalary, hoursWorked, grossPay);
    }//end main

    static void showOutput(int[] departmentCount, double hourlySalary, double hoursWorked, double grossPay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grosspay for each department");
        Console.WriteLine("Department\t Employees");

        for (int i = 0; i < departmentCount.Length; i++)
        {
            if (departmentCount[i] != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t {1}\t\t {2}\t\t {3}\t\t {4}", i + 1, departmentCount[i], hourlySalary, hoursWorked, grossPay);
            }//end if
        }//end for
    }//end showOutput
}
}
```

Here is the data I'm using to test my program:

```
EID500,2,45,50
EID558,1,82,43
EID244,3,17,46
EID96,4,71,16
EID420,7,55,22
EID528,5,14,49
EID469,6,26,21
EID983,6,72,40
EID968,4,36,40
EID811,4,26,47
EID937,4,76,3
EID319,1,29,17
EID962,2,23,37
EID239,2,83,49
EID112,5,43,42
EID840,4,75,30
EID621,3,81,32
EID192,1,50,52
EID732,5,47,6
EID932,1,54,24
EID634,7,44,45
EID592,1,48,43
EID745,4,60,14
EID169,4,95,29
EID705,2,47,53
EID273,5,17,57
EID772,2,89,31
EID820,6,90,6
EID82,7,16,56
EID66,7,91,33
EID993,1,80,44
EID455,2,73,16
EID758,7,44,41
EID600,5,21,57
EID818,4,98,19
EID191,7,91,2
EID567,4,23,12
EID400,1,47,44
EID329,7,91,13
EID900,3,54,33
EID562,5,78,53
EID340,2,54,29
EID838,1,20,38
EID981,5,42,6
EID159,6,24,59
EID65,4,86,44
EID515,5,42,44
EID694,7,14,28
EID941,4,78,34
EID136,1,70,22
```

Arrays are the most advanced function I can use, as we haven't learned the List item I've read about on a few other articles here.
Do I have to create arrays for the hourly salary and the hours worked?

Any help is much appreciated.

-Henry

Comment: I don't think *I run into trouble.* is enough of an explanation for a question here.

Comment: Hi Henry, I don't want to point out too much to you and short cut your education.

It doesn't look like you are doing anything with grosspay at the end. It gets reset every time.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama I know, my program is still a work in progress. After working on it for hours this morning, I took a little break, and will get back to it soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a candidate for the code review site. They can give you some very useful tips how to solve these problems in a better way. On the other hand, if you're constrained to a subset of C# and the BCL (as you say) then good luck.

Comment: @usr The problem with a code review is that this is student material and you don't know the teacher's curriculum.  Courses start out slow and cumbersome, like using student1 thru student10, and later learn about arrays such as student[9].  Don't know if the teacher will get upset if one goes too fast (such as using Decimal instead of Double).  If this was a business user and not a student, a code review would make sense.

Comment: @RickDavin yes. On the other hand it doesn't meet the professionalism bar required on SO.

Comment: The OP stated upfront that he was a student and SO has a lower bar for homework-related code, because after all, they are in the early stages of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to use arrays for hourly salary but you do need to have another variable.  Don't get me wrong - perhaps an array would be cleaner.  Consider this snippet:

```
if (double.TryParse(employee[2], out hourlySalary) && hourlySalary >= 10.0)
                hourlySalary = hourlySalary + hourlySalary;
```

You need to have one salary variable for a total, and another for the current record input record.  I'd suggest you rename the hourlySalary defined outside of the loop to totalHourlySalary.  Then define another one inside the loop.

```
double hourlySalary
if (double.TryParse(employee[2], out hourlySalary) && hourlySalary >= 10.0)
                totalHourlySalary = totalHourlySalary + hourlySalary;
```

Comment: If possible, I'd prefer to keep it simple through the use of variables, like how you described. I'll give it a try, and report back later.

Comment: If it works, please mark the answer that worked best for you ... hopefully  mine :-)  I trust you realize that you were wiping out the previous value of hourlySalary, which caused the bad results.  Good luck.

Comment: While both answers helped me to some extent, yours helped me that much more. Also, you didn't degrade me for being a beginner. Thanks a lot.